# MapPageRoute with Similar routeURL

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need this sort of redirect to happen in my application:

/car
go to  show-all-cars.aspx

/car/1234
go to  edit-car.aspx

This is my current code in global.asax:

```
routeCollection.MapPageRoute("car-edit",
                "car/{id}",
                "~/car-edit.aspx",
                true,
                new RouteValueDictionary { { "id" } });

routeCollection.MapPageRoute("car-all",
                "car",
                "~/show-all-cars.aspx",
                true);
```

For some reason, going to /car results in a redirect to car-edit.aspx instead of show-all-cars.aspx as needed.

Any ideas?

Webforms C#.NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap the both routes, i.e put the second route before the first.